# Can I randomize items in MultipleChoiceItem?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-classroom

I'm new to GoogleAppsScript and now making quizzes in google form and spreadsheet by using GAS.

I want to shuffle items in a MultipleChoiceItem when the google form is reloaded.

A part of my current scirpt, slightly modified form [this code](https://github.com/mattbellis/using-Google-Forms-quizzes-with-a-testbank), is presented below.

```
//vars from spreadsheet
var form = FormApp.openById(id);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(question_bank_ID);
var text = sheet.getSheetValues(questions[i]+1, 2, 1, 1)[0][0];
var options = sheet.getSheetValues(questions[i]+1, 5, 1, 5)[0];
var ans = sheet2.getSheetValues(questions[i]+1, 5, 1, 5)[0];

//MultipleChoiceItem
var mc = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle(text);
        mc.setPoints(1) // set point 
         // add choices with isCorrect
        while (options[options.length - 1] === "") {
          options.pop();
        }
        mc.setChoices(options.map(function (options, i) {
          return mc.createChoice(options, ans[i]);
        }
                                 )
                      )
```

Could someone please tell me a solution? Thanks for your help!

Comment: "when the google form is reloaded" Do you mean when the editor version of the form is reloaded or when a user is refreshing the Form URL he received? The first is possible, the second not without the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I hope to implement the second one in order to give each user (student) the same qiuz with different order of questions and choices. setShuffleQuestions() might be for randomizing question, but I couldn't find the similar function for shuffling items.

Comment: Unfortunately a similar method for shuffling items does not exist. I updated my answer with the best workaround I could come up with.

Comment: I see. I'll try alternative solution you mentioned. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Now, I use Moodle, a learning management system, in place of google forms for making tests with randomized items from quiz bank. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: By releasing Google Forms API on March 16, 2022, your goal can be directly achieved using it. [Ref](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/03/google-forms-api-generally-available.html) You can see the sample script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71745819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained there is no direct answer to this, which is rather surprising considering there is an option to *Shuffle option order* via the front end interface. ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcJr2.png))

To me, the proposals of triggering reshuffles every 1 minute are too inefficient and it does not ensure that the order will change for each user. In my opinion, a *less bad* approach (though not a solution) would be to manually create a `MultipleChoiceItem` that has the Shuffle option order checked, then [duplicate the MultipleChoiceItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item?hl=en#duplicate), rather than create a new one.

You would need to have some hard-coded reference such as [get the ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item?hl=en#getid) for the `MultipleChoiceItem` , but once you have that you could continually create as many questions as needed that would do exactly what this question asks.

Here's a sample item as well as a function to display the ID of all multiple-choice items in a form. It's not perfect, but perhaps an alternative.

```
function makeShuffledQuestion() {
  const theIDofShuffleQuestion = 2???????1; //<--- must find by getID()

  const theShuffleQuestion = form.getItemById(theIDofShuffleQuestion);

  //next line use duplicate, or start loops to duplicate types that
  var mc = theShuffleQuestion.duplicate();
  mc.setTitle("This one is new!");
  mc.setPoints(1);
  mc.setChoices([
    mc.createChoice("alpha", fale),
    mc.createChoice("bravo", false),
    mc.createChoice("charlie", true),
    mc.createChoice("delta", false)
  ])
}

function listAllItemsID() {
  //function will display all multiplie choice items with title and ID
  var allItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
  for (var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(allItems[i].getTitle() + "  ID:" + allItems[i].getId().toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- In order to shuffle your values each time your form is reloaded, you need to bind to your form a script with an `onOpen` [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- Retrieve all questions and for each question retrieve the choices
- Use a shuffle function to randomize the choices
- Assign the shuffled choices back to the question

### Sample:

```
function onOpen(){
  form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var questions = form.getItems();
  for (var i =0; i < questions.length; i++){
    var question = questions[i];
    var choices = question.asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices();
    var newChoices = shuffle(choices);
    question.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoices(newChoices);
  }

}


function shuffle(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
```

### UPDATE:

If you want to give to every user the same quiz but with randomized questions, there is no direct way to do it - so far there is no method of the kind `setShuffleItems`. 
All you can do for the moment is a workaround, e.g. **you can bind to the sample above an [installable time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)** which would shuffle the items in desired intervals (the minimum is one minute). This does not guarantee that each user will see a different quiz, but at least each minute the quiz will be different.