# Trying to shuffle the answers inside a multiple choice question (Google forms)

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

While I can use the
`form.setShuffleQuestions(true);`
function, I cannot find a way to randomize the answers.
The same question has been asked here [Shuffle answer properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549604/shuffle-answer-properties) but I am not sure if the answer is what I need.
Thank you.

Comment: [Edit] to use proper tags(like [tag:google-apps-script], [tag:google-forms]). I've added a answer to that question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shuffle answer properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549604/shuffle-answer-properties)